# Why are some packages installing init-scripts and systemd config files? Aren't init-scripts superfluous by now?

Tags: systemd, init.d

nginx for example installs:

```
/etc/init.d/nginx

/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service
```

https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/all/nginx-common/filelist

Shouldn't `/etc/init.d/nginx` be removed from the package? Shouldn't all init-scripts removed, as ubuntu now uses systemd? Or at least moved into seperated packages?

Nginx is of course just an example.

Comment: **backwards compatibility** ?

Comment: that ^ and it is up to the -maintainer- of the package not canonical.

Comment: So if I use systemd I don't need those any more? They are not used by any other software?

@Rinzwind Yes, I did not mean to "blame" canonical. I just wonder why? I could also ask, why would the maintainer think, it is a good idea?